# Começando com Vue.js com experiência de jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Tenho  experiencia com JavaScript e jQuery e depois de alguns anos resolvi sair da minha zona de conforto e conhecer novos horizontes.  Fiz um passeio rápido pelo Angular até chegar no Vue.js.

Existe uma dúvida que gostaria de esclarecer com os amigos, afinal de contas, o Vue substitui o jQuery?  Ou eles não tem nada a ver um com o outro?

O que o Vue faz que o jQuery não faz e vice-versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) e jQuery podem ser complementares ou exclusivos dependendo do que queres fazer.

Mas em modo geral a resposta é se usas vue.js então não precisas de jQuery.

O conceito por trás de bibliotecas modernas como o vue.js ou React.js é terem mecanismos internos para redesenhar a página e conteúdos. Esse tipo de "trabalho" era tipicamente feito por bibliotecas como MooTools ou jQuery. Assim sem a necessidade de tais ferramentas o que acontece é bibliotecas antigas caírem em desuso.

Se tens alguma funcionalidade que o vue.js não faça (por exemplo requiesição AJAX, ou um plugin específico do jQuery) então podes usar jQuery. Se não, então não precisas mais de jQuery.

Nota que se usares jQuery provavelmente tens de o inserir [através de compilador como webpack ou browserify](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments). Encontrei um para o [webpack](http:///vuejs/vue-loader) e outro para o [browserify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify), mas isso é uma pergunta à parte.

Comment: "por exemplo requiesição AJAX" Não entendi, Vue não faz consumo por Ajax?

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de agradecer sua resposta que foi muito esclarecedora.

Comment: @NixonGirard ontem não tive tempo para voltar aqui, e hoje vi a tua [nova pergunta e respondi lá](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173476/129). Como referi lá o `vue` tem ajax mas não no ficheiro principal, tens de juntar mais um script. Por vezes, por necessidade ou por se gostar mais.